# android getResources().openRawResource() return error

Tags: android, eclipse

i'm developing some android app, i have the same files shared from this project, i put it in a folder on my mac. 
I put my files in raw folder of my project without copy but only linked the file.
The function `getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.filename)` return me an error and said me that `can't find the files`.

Why? I'm using eclipse.

thank you in advance

Comment: Copy. Do not use link.

Comment: ok, but i have ten project with the same file shared, and i like to modify only one time this file for take updates to all projects..is possible?

Comment: Include it in a single library project. All your 10 projects should use this library.